# Minikube ingress not working in Windows 10 professional

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I'm trying to run/set up ingress in Minikube. But it is not happening. Here are the steps
Environment:

- Windows 10 professional
- minikube version: v1.24.0

**Ingress enabled:**

| ingress                     | minikube | enabled ✅   | unknown (third-party) | 
| ingress-dns                 | minikube | enabled ✅   | unknown (third-party) |

**Create Deployment**

```
    $ kubectl get deployment

NAME                  READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/web   1/1     1            1           9s
```

**Expose service**

```
kubectl expose deployment web --type=NodePort --port=8080

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          38h
web          NodePort    10.103.21.35   <none>        8080:30945/TCP   3m22s
```

**Start Service**

```
minikube service web

Browser url: http://127.0.0.1:59188/

Browser content: 
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: web-79d88c97d6-c79mp
```

**Create ingress:**

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/service/networking/example-ingress.yaml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/example-ingress unchanged


$ kubectl get ingress
NAME              CLASS   HOSTS              ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   nginx   hello-world.info   localhost   80      14h
```

**Add map hosts:**

```
> in /etc/hosts
> 127.0.0.1 hello-world.info and in windows/system32/etc/hosts 
> 127.0.0.1 hello-world.info
```

**Run curl command: (from a new git bash I executing the following command)**

```
$ curl hello-world.info
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to hello-world.info port 80: Connection refused
```

In browser:

```
    URL: http://hello-world.info/
    Browser content: This site can't be reached 
hello-world.info refused to connect.
```

***not sure why I'm getting failure. Request help here.***

Answer (score 2):

You can get your minikube cluster ip with below and proceed.

minikube ip

Add this ip to /etc/hosts

Comment: added minikube ip in /etc/hosts and C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and did curl in new window the result is "curl: (28) Failed to connect to hello-world.info port 80: Timed out"

Comment: Did you clean up old local host entries. Also check of you are able to reach your app via nodeport

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's 2 issues at play here after testing various scenarios.

1. An issue with the current latest minikube, v1.24.0, which messes with the minikube ingress addon and makes the address for the ingress be localhost instead of being the same as the `minikube ip`
2. An issue with the docker driver which prevents the `minikube ip` from being accessible through curl and the browser.

To resolve both of these issues I downgraded minikube to the previous version, v1.23.2, and then used the HyperV driver, after which the examples and tutorials on the Kubernetes site began to work as intended.

---

Below are the full steps I took:

Delete any previous instances of minikube that was spun up using v1.24.0 with the same version prior to downgrading just to be safe

```
minikube delete
```

Download and replace the minikube executable with [v1.23.2](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.23.2)

Check that you replaced the executable correctly

```
minikube version
```

Turn on HyperV in *Turn Windows features on or off*

Restart the computer

Create a new minikube instance, but this time with HyperV

```
minikube start --driver=hyperv
```

Enable the ingress addon in minikube

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Deploy all the deployment, service and ingress to this new instance.

Wait a minute or so until an address is assigned to the ingress. Once it's there, update the hosts file and route the domain to the address.

Now check both the address and the domain via curl and/or the browser to see if the issue's resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I also use minikube v1.24 on Windows.
After type the command

`minikube tunnel`

Browse URL: http://hello-world.info/ can return the correct content.